# C Dynamic Memory

Tags: c, memory, dynamic

I don't understand why this program is working.

```
char *a;
    a=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(a,"aaaaaaaaaa");
    printf("%s",a);
```

I am allocating only 10 character array with 10th character being the '\0' character. So why it is still printing string with length of more that 10?

Comment: First of all, never cast the return value of `malloc`. Second, `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so it is redundant. Third, you are allocating 10 bytes, but the string you are copying to it is 11 bytes. This should cause undefined behavior

Comment: This is an undefined behavior, on your test your are lucky you have a null just after.

Comment: Tens of thousands of duplicates:(

Comment: I see 10 a's which makes that 11 long with the \0, so you are overflowing your allocated space

Comment: Yes i know that i am overflowing. But this doesn't cause any error whatsoever, why? I mean, is the program automatically reserving space for the overflowed characters, if so why we even need realloc() ?

Comment: @Nagato, C does not promise that you will receive an error when you overrun array bounds.  It merely says that the resulting behavior is *undefined*.  There are *many*, *many* discussions of UB here already, including a fair number focusing on more or less the exact situation you present.  You could receive an error.  You could observe apparently-normal behavior.  Your machine could initiate its self-destruct sequence.  Were it within the machine's power to cause it, demons might fly out of your nose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've allocated this much memory:

```
| | | | | | | | | | |
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

You've written this much:

```
|a|a|a|a|a|a|a|a|a|a|\0|
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

One too many.
This is considered *[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*.
Or, in *[more colorful terms.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)* (As referenced @John Bollinger in the comments.)

Comment: This helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because this program is not referencing a invalid memory position. The next memory cell position in memory is not "important". If you try with more characters you'll get the segmentation fault.

This code works for me.

```
void main() {
    char *a;
    long int i;

    a=(char*)malloc(900001*sizeof(char));
    for (i=0;i<900000;i++) a[i]='a';
    a[i]='\0';
    printf("%s",a);
}
```

But modifying reserved space in malloc to a little memory space, causes a segmentation fault , normal behavior

```
void main() {
    char *a;
    long int i;

    a=(char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    for (i=0;i<900000;i++) a[i]='a';
    a[i]='\0';
    printf("%s",a);
}
```

An incorrect access memory is forced!

Comment: never cast the result of a malloc